# Partially overlapping try-finally blocks

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch, il

While reading up on [Exception handling clauses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.exceptionhandlingclauseoptions(v=vs.110).aspx), I noticed that it's theoretically possible to create partially overlapping try-finally blocks in IL. In other words:

```
0000: [code]
0001: [code]
0002: [code]

0003: [code]
0004: endfinally

0005: [code]
0006: endfinally

.try 0000 to 0002 finally handler 0003 to 0005 (1st handler)
.try 0001 to 0003 finally handler 0005 to 0007 (2nd handler)
```

This would imply that if 0000 throws an exception, the 1st handler would be hit, if 0001 throws an exception both handlers would be hit and if 0002 throws an exception only the second would be hit.

Also, it's possible to make more strange handler definitions, like:

```
.try 0003 to 0005 finally handler 0005 to 0007 (3rd handler)
```

Q1: Are these strange kinds of handlers even allowed, or are there rules that dictate otherwise?

Q2: And if they are allowed, are there scenario's in a normal programming language where this kind of weird code is actually generated?

Comment: Does the IL pass PEVerify?

Comment: @leppie I haven't tested; although I see your point, for these kinds of things I prefer to just know "the truth". Especially since my tool is also intended to replace PEVerify (I'm always having trouble with that while working with Emit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not valid, per [MS Partition I](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa569283.aspx) of the Common Language Infrastructure, section 12.4.2.7:

> Every method can have associated with it a set of **exception entries**, called the **exception set**.
>
> ...
>
> For every pair of exception entries in an exception set, one of the following must be true:
>
> - They **nest**: all three regions of one entry shall be within a single region of the other entry, with the
>     further restriction that the enclosing region shall not be a filter. [*Note*: Functions called from within
>     a filter can contain exception handling. *end note*]
> - They are **disjoint**: all six regions of the two entries are pairwise-disjoint (no addresses overlap).
> - They **mutually protect**: the protected blocks are the same and the other regions are pairwisedisjoint.
>     In this case, all handlers shall be either catch handlers or filtered handlers. The precedence
>     of the handler regions is determined by their ordering in the Exception Handler Table (Partition II).

Since your protected blocks are neither nested, not disjoint, nor exactly the same, they meet none of these requirements and so this exception set is invalid.